# Combine multiple byte[] to one multi page Base64

Tags: c#, base64, byte

I am reading SQL Reports from c#. The report only accepts one subscription Guid at a time.

```
   private byte[] GetCertificate(Guid sub)
    {
        var parameters = new[]
        {
            new ParameterValue {Name = "SubscriptionID", Value = sub.ToString()}
        };

        return ReportServices.Generate("/Reports/Certificate", parameters);
    }

    private byte[] GetCertificates(List<EntityReference> subscriptions)
    {
        var bytes = new List<byte>();
        foreach (var sub in subscriptions)
        {
            bytes.AddRange(GetCertificate(sub.Id));
        }
        return bytes.ToArray();
    }

   AdditionalDocBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(GetCertificates(subscriptions))
```

I need to combine these Certificates into one Base64String. However, when I do this it only creates one PDF wheres there can be multiple.

Comment: what does composing multiple subscriptions mean here? are you just trying to concatenate the byte[] into a single blob, and then run it through base-64? would that give the desired result? or is there something more nuanced involved to represent multiple PDFs?

Comment: Each byte[] will contain information relating to a specific subscription. I was hoping that I've combined this into a single blob it would then run it through base-64 it would be a concatenation of each subscription eg Base64 = sub1 + sub2+ sub3. However, when i run the base64 string through a decoder it only has the last item in the loop.

Comment: if you concatenate multiple blobs and run it through base-64, you will get the contents of all of them, end-to-end; if you're not seeing that, then *something is wrong with your concatenate and base-64 step*, because that works just fine - see here: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/1177e9e07d310ca0eedcb0af64e680c3 - very hard to be more specific here because I can't run your code